# Azure Function CosmosDb Binding Performace

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

How to measure performance of the Azure Function binding to CosmosDb?
On one hand, how can I profile the CosmosDb account for activity?
On the other hand, how can I measure the binding activity of the Azure Function Host?

Comment: what performance exactly do you want to measure? And what binding are you using? Cosmos DB change feed trigger?

Comment: "what performance exactly do you want to measure?"
Cost of the request made from an Azure Function to Cosmos DB.
"And what binding are you using?"
Input & Output (not trigger)
"Cosmos DB change feed trigger?"
No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RU metrics metrics are abstracted away from you when you are using the input / output binding. If you need that level of detail / control, you will need to use the client binding as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#http-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-documentclient-c).

Comment: Silent, thanks for your answer. Let me wait for a couple of weeks if people would like to add some insights. If no better answer would appear, I will mark yours as an answer. Thanks.